# rails 4 Test case :NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for ArticleTest:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I am begginer in rails "test" cases. for practice purpose i have writtin one test case where i am checking if saved object is valid or not. after running this test case i am getting error as `NoMethodError: undefined method create for ArticleTest:Class` . i am following rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

```
require 'test_helper'

class ArticleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   test "the truth" do
     @article = ArticleTest.create
     assert @article.valid?
   end
end
```

what is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.

Model name was "Article" and i was writing "ArticleTest"